# How to use data from unrelated tables in MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I don't know if this is possible...

I have two unrelated tables: `Data` and `Emails`. They are impossible to relate because the `Emails` table only keeps several email html body's.

**My question is: How can I use (and edit both data) from these tables under the same form?**

`Data table` contains client (table fields): `name`, `email`, and `adress`

The fields on this table are all default `text` type.

`Emails table` contains several email texts (table fields): (`email 1`, `email 2`, `email 3`, etc.).

For each email (row), I have these columns: (mail_subject & html_body). The column `html body` is set to default `memo` type. The column `subject` is set to default `text` type.

The form for each email should query `Emails table` by `subject`.

**This is my Data Table**

```
+-------+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
|   id  |   name    |         email        |        address      |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
|   1   |   John    |   email1@blablabla   |  address number 1   |
|   2   |   Mary    |   email2@blablabla   |  address number 2   |
|   3   |   Jeff    |   email3@blablabla   |  address number 3   |
|   4   |   Bill    |   email4@blablabla   |  address number 4   |
|   5   |   Bob     |   email5@blablabla   |  address number 5   |
+-------+-----------+----------------------+---------------------+
```

**This is my Emails Table**

```
+-------+----------------------+------------------+
|   id  |     mail_subject     |    html_body     |
+-------+----------------------+------------------+
|   1   |   subject number 1   |  <body>1</body>  |
|   2   |   subject number 2   |  <body>2</body>  |
|   3   |   subject number 3   |  <body>3</body>  |
|   4   |   subject number 4   |  <body>4</body>  |
|   5   |   subject number 5   |  <body>5</body>  |
+-------+----------------------+------------------+
```

**This is my actual SQL:**

`SELECT [Emails Table].MailSubject, [Emails Table].html_body, [Data Table].*
FROM [Data Table], [Emails Table]
WHERE (((Emails.MailSubject)="subject number 1"));`

With this, I can get all data on my form, but I can't edit any fields and I need it. Another problem with this query is that I also cannot use the `subject` and `html body` in my VBA Code when sending the email (`.HTMLBody = "" & Me.html_body & "" & _`)

I hope this can be clear enough...

Comment: Please post table definitions to support your question.

Comment: Sample data and desired results, please.

Comment: @krishKM Should I put this in pictures?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I've edited my question. See, if you got enough elements, please.

Comment: The question is: how do you ***want*** to use that unrelated data on only one form. If your form shall display data from the `Emails table`, what do you need the data from the `Data table` for (in this form)?

Comment: @WolfgangKais I have the main form where I work client information. When needed, I have to open the email form where the client `name` and `email` are equal.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your original question. So you don't want the form to display the records from the `Emails table` but instead show the records from the `Data table` (filtered by `name` and `email` coming from another form)?

Comment: @WolfgangKais I want to use data from both tables in the same form. And yes, I need to filter the data this way (when I open the email form): `name`, `email` & `address` coming from the main form/data table, to that client email and address. And the `subject` (coming from emails table) so I can get all the fields that compose the email I need to send.

Comment: I think that you should post an input of data example, and also the desired output you would like to obtain.

Comment: It has been mentioned, but still: [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3820271). Sample data and expected result is much more useful than a textual description. Note: Sample data != real data.

Comment: Without exactly clarifying what you have tried vs. what you want to see. The only thing i can recommend is using subforms. You can display data despite no having any relation on the parent form. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). What is the purpose of your form? Are you sending out emails to client and need to choose from emails in email table(s)?

Comment: @Parfait I´ve updated my question. Please see I have provide enough elements.

Comment: *How can I use (and edit both data) ...* How do you want to use the two unrelated tables? You can set up two subforms on an unbound main form.